# Is there a way to integrate by parts the integrand $\frac{\sin x}{x}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I was trying for a while to find the integral of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and didn't succeed. Maybe I have done mistakes, so I would like to know if this integral is to be found by integration by parts ? Thanks for any comment.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)

Comment: $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not integrable in finite terms. Its leads to a new function called *sin integral*  look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral

Comment: Are you looking for the value over an interval?

$$
\int_0^{+\infty} {\rm d}x~\frac{\sin x}{x}
$$

Comment: Yes, how you would compute $\int_0^{+\infty} {\rm d}x~\frac{\sin x}{x}$ ?

Comment: or see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral

Comment: @user249018 From my knowledge, evaluating the improper integral from 0 to $+\infty$ requires higher level mathematics such as Laplace Transform properties or Complex Analysis.

Answer (score 1):

This function has no elementary anti-derivative and as such is just treated as the Sine Integral.

If you can accept an answer in terms of a series, $$\frac{sin(x)}{x}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2i}(-1)^{i-1}}{(2i+1)!}$$

So $$\int \frac{sin(x)}{x}dx=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2i+1}(-1)^{i-1}}{(2i+1)(2i+1)!}+C$$

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the integration by parts or any other method, since it was proved by Joseph Liouville! The integral of $$ \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$ is defined by 
$$ \operatorname{Si}(t) := \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \,dx.$$

I suppose that there is a numerical method how you can compute this value.